# How to concatinate text on existing database entry?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a table, whose fields are

```
id, name, link
```

the link holds the name of the page like "link" = "index.php". Now I want to update this field
and add "page=" in front of "index.php". Using this method I would like to update every entry in my table.

My desired SQL syntax need to be something like this

```
UPDATE mytable set link= 'page=' + <existing value of link>;
```

Anyone know what to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using MySQL you can try:

```
UPDATE mytable SET link = CONCAT("page:", link)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE mytable Set link = "page:" || link
```

Comment: @Starx: that is puzzling - it ought to work.  The WHERE 1 condition in your question is unnecessary; it is implied by the absence of any WHERE clause.  You say that the links were changed to 0?  I suppose that if a DBMS did something...scrappily...then if you use '+' in place of the '||' then you might get both strings converted to numbers, which fails, leading to a dummy value of zero.  However, you have to have mistyped the SET clause and the DBMS has to be buggy, so it is implausible.

Comment: I have removed the WHERE statement, and may be the reason for your sql not to work is the fact that I am was using mysql.